# A more efficient way to organize a DB schema for key value storage in a related table

Tags: sql, sqlite

Here is the DB schema that I currently use (some tables and table columns have been removed and the rest have been renamed for simplicity).
I've added some indexes and at the bottom there are sample *INSERT* and *SELECT* queries that I frequently execute.

My question is: **How can I further optimize the DB schema by adding / removing some indexes or changing some data types.** The question mostly concerns the *eventTypeParameterValues* table and its *value* column which could take on arbitrary values (hence specified as *TEXT* here) some of which can be IDs of columns of other tables.

EDIT: The *value* column currently does NOT use an index when filtering on it. Should I add one?

```
CREATE TABLE "objects"(
    objectId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE CHECK(LENGTH(name) > 0),
    label TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE CHECK(LENGTH(label) > 0)
);

CREATE INDEX index_objects_label ON "objects"(label);
INSERT INTO "objects"(name, label) 
    VALUES
        ('foo sfsdf', 'foo foo'),
        ('bar bar bar', 'bar');



CREATE TABLE "eventTypes"(
    eventTypeId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    label TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE CHECK(LENGTH(label) > 0)
);
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO "eventTypes"(label)
    VALUES
        ('foo'),
        ('bar'),
        ('bla'),
        -- ...
        ('bla bla');


CREATE TABLE "events"(
    eventId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    eventTypeId INT NOT NULL REFERENCES "eventTypes"(eventTypeId) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
CREATE INDEX index_events_eventTypeId ON "events"(eventTypeId);


CREATE TABLE "eventTypeParameters"(
    eventTypeParameterId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    label TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE CHECK(LENGTH(label) > 0)
);
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO "eventTypeParameters"(label)
    VALUES
        ('param1ObjectId'),
        ('param1'),
        ('param2ObjectId'),
        ('param2'),
        ('param3'),
        -- ...
        ('param1000');


CREATE TABLE "eventTypeParameterValues"(
    eventTypeParameterValueId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    eventId INT NOT NULL REFERENCES "events"(eventId) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    eventTypeParameterId INT NOT NULL REFERENCES "eventTypeParameters"(eventTypeParameterId) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    value TEXT NOT NULL
);
CREATE INDEX index_eventTypeParameterValues_eventId ON "eventTypeParameterValues"(eventId);
CREATE INDEX index_eventTypeParameterValues_eventTypeParameterId ON "eventTypeParameterValues"(eventTypeParameterId);


-- a sample event
INSERT INTO "events"(eventTypeId)
    VALUES((SELECT eventTypeId FROM eventTypes WHERE label = 'bar'));
INSERT INTO "eventTypeParameterValues"(eventId, eventTypeParameterId, value)
    VALUES((SELECT MAX(eventId) FROM events), (SELECT eventTypeParameterId FROM eventTypeParameters WHERE label = 'param2ObjectId'), (SELECT objectId FROM objects WHERE label = 'bar'));
INSERT INTO "eventTypeParameterValues"(eventId, eventTypeParameterId, value)
    VALUES((SELECT MAX(eventId) FROM events), (SELECT eventTypeParameterId FROM eventTypeParameters WHERE label = 'param3'), 'sdfasf sflsfjlsd');



SELECT ppv1.value FROM "events" t 
    INNER JOIN "eventTypeParameterValues" ppv1 ON t.eventId = ppv1.eventId
    INNER JOIN "eventTypeParameterValues" ppv2 ON t.eventId = ppv2.eventId
    WHERE t.eventTypeId = 2 AND ppv1.eventTypeParameterId = 3
        AND ppv2.eventTypeParameterId = 5 AND ppv2.value = 'sdfasf sflsfjlsd';
```

**EDIT 2**: Since work on this project has just begun, more radical DB schema changes are NOT out of the question. So feel free to suggest even more drastic changes.

Comment: DBFIddle says this uses indexes for all joins/where clauses. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9Bs3newCqeCSvtjnbKtnY5/0  - is that true on your "real" system?

Comment: Yeah, I believe that the table joins are OK with the current indexes. I am more worried about filtering on `ppv2.value = `, where the *value* column currently doesn't use an index. See the EDIT

Comment: If you need a flexible set of parameters, you might consider using the JSON extension instead of an EAV (entity-attribute-value) model.

Comment: @GordonLinoff performance is of critical performance here (once the tables reach in the tens of millions of rows) and I am sure that parsing (when reading) and generating (when writing) JSON is going to result in a major performance hit. Besides, the table structure is kinda known. It's just that the `value` column needs to be flexible accepting all kinds of values: row IDs but also various numbers, strings and even dates.

Comment: @logicReasoner . . . Almost certainly not -- unless you have lots of parameters that significantly increase the width of each row.  In addition, SQLite allows indexes on JSON.  And, if you know the table format, then structure the data as a table with separate columns, not using EAV!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite uses only one index per table in your query. Adding more indices is unlikely to improve performance of your query.

Based on your sample query, you'd benefit from the following indices:

```
events (eventId, eventTypeId)
eventTypeParameterValues (eventId, eventTypeParameterId, value)
```

It's hard to say whether that would actually improve performance without seeing your EXPLAIN as it is today. When I tried this on db-fiddle, the index on eventTypeParameterValues is used, but not the one on events, presumably because in the sample data, eventTypeId isn't sufficiently distributed.

Adding these indices will help if the following are true:

- in the events table for any given event ID, there can be thousands of event types.
- in the eventTypeParameterValues table, for any given eventID, there can be thousands of combinations of eventTypeParamenterID and value

Your current EXPLAIN says that when searching the eventTypeParameterValues, the query optimizer uses an index to find all the records matching the foreign key to events. If that yields a set of "some" (<1000?) records, the additional index is unlikely to make a huge difference. If it yields "lost" (>100.000?), it will make a huge difference.

The good news is that you don't need to worry too much - if you create the compound index, you can drop `index_eventTypeParameterValues_eventId` as its covered by the compound index.

Comment: Well, since work on the project has just started, I have only a little bit of dummy data stored in the DB. Here's the EXPLAIN generated by DB Browser for SQLite (running on Linux). https://pastebin.com/XgygM9WR (updated link). BTW, I am going to use SQLite from a C++ application.

Comment: If I create a new DB with the covering indexes that you suggested instead:
```
CREATE INDEX index_eventTypeParameterValues_eventId ON "eventTypeParameterValues"(eventId, eventTypeParameterId, value);
CREATE INDEX index_events_eventTypeId ON "events"(eventId, eventTypeId);
```, 
I get a table scan on eventTypeParameterValues: https://pastebin.com/DZjmqM4h
Not sure if because I only have two rows there...

Comment: Probably because the query optimizer has figured out the selectivity is so low - without that index, the optimizer is using different indexes for the searching of eventTypeParameterValues. How many rows do you reasonably anticipate?

Comment: Somewhere in the tens of millions once the project is up and running.

Comment: In that case, the covering index is probably the way to go; generate test data and see how the app responds.